Manage Master AWS RDS DB credentials with Secrets Manager for SpringBoot project
I have researched how to integrate secrets manager to manage my master DB credentials for my AWS RDS DB. I have seen multiple ways of doing this, but nothing has worked locally. In my use case with integrating with RDS, the credentials are added when the backend is built by Jenkins. I've seen spring cloud (io.awspring.cloud) be used to manage the jdbc connection however, I'm stuck with leveraging this approach. I am relatively new to AWS, so any advice is helpful!
my secret is a regular key-pair value with username/password as keys and the values
I am using application.properties and I have added:
spring.config.import=optional:aws-secretsmanager:dbName
aws.secretsmanager.region=myregion
spring.datasource.username=${username}
spring.datasource.password=${password} 
I've also added the following in my POM:

<groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
2.4.4

I am using Spring 2.7.7
Would I need to update my spring.datasource.url as well to match my RDS Endpoint? What about AWS Credentials? When I've tried this locally I continue getting an Access Denied error, but my end goal is to have this on my RDS, just figured testing before implementing would be a bit smoother. In my RDS  I modified my master credentials to use secrets manager which generates a new secret without a lambda. Any ideas on how if this approach is the correct one to do for my RDS implementation? The RDS also talks to an EC2 instance, would env variables be useful here?
